# Python Rename Filename With Substring Best Practices

Tags: python-2.7, etl

Simplified, I have a data file:

```
P.A2057.ACO.QASSGN.D150218.T1200333.xls
```

I successfully copy it to a directory "MSSP_DATA_ARCHIVE" for documentation here:

```
dest_dir = "C:/Users/Office/Desktop/TEST/MSSP_DATA_ARCHIVE/"
for file in glob.glob(r'C:/Users/Office/Desktop/TEST/LOAD/*.xls'):
    print file
    shutil.copy(file, dest_dir)
```

I would like to rename the original version still sitting in "LOAD" to this:

```
QASSGN.xls
```

I will not know the exact name of the file monthly (appears to be at least partially randomly generated for some elements).

I am hoping to substring the current filename to extract the desired name above.

Here is what I have started:

```
for file in glob.glob(r'C:/Users/Office/Desktop/TEST/LOAD/*.xls'):
    parts = file.split('.') 

    parts = ['C:/Users/Office/Desktop/TEST/LOAD\\P',
             'A2057', 'ACO', 'QASSGN', 'D150218', 'T1200333','xls']
```

I know there must be a better way to handle this with **os.path.splitext** and **os.rename** to avoid getting into "magic numbers" trouble.  Not very pythonic.

Any pointers would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: I think you have too many details which are irrelevant here, but I dont know enough to edit the post. it seems your question boils down to renaming a file with a specific name format to a different name format. is this correct?

Comment: just providing context.  i will cut it down a bit. indeed, you are correct.

Comment: If it's always the fourth component you want to use, then perhaps something like `newname = '.'.join([file.split('.')[3], 'xls'])` would be of interest, combined with a subsequent `os.rename(...)` with the appropriate parameters (or the related call from `shutil`, since you're already using it)...

Comment: what are you trying to rename the file to exactly? preferably with 2 examples or so of expected input (as different as possible) and the output you would like

Comment: @twalberg that certainly points me in the right direction to get me here for file in glob.glob(r'C:/Users/Office/Desktop/TEST/LOAD/*.xls'):
    new_name = '.'.join([file.split('.')[3], 'xls'])
    os.rename('C:/Users/Office/Desktop/TEST/LOAD/*.xls', new_name)  but the issue is that os.rename needs the exact name/path which I am trying to avoid because of the random numbers in the original filename.

Comment: @pseudonym117 P.A2057.ACO.QASSGN.D150218.T1200333.xls to QASSGN.xls Unfortunately, this is the only test file provided.  I believe that later two sections starting with "D" and "T" are the offenders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that your input always as your desired name as the 4th section in the filename. Only 1 thing is a magic number, as I dont know of another way you expect your data to be named.

```
# the path of your files
path = 'C:\\Users\\Office\\Desktop\\TEST\\LOAD'
# the place you want to output your files
# set to input because i have no idea where you want them
dest_path = path
# the type of files you want to rename
ext = r'xls'

# file will contain the path of the file
for file in glob.glob('{path}\\*.{ext}'.format(path=path, ext=ext)):
    # the filename we are going to change (dont want the path at all)
    name = file.split('\\')[-1]

    # the new name of the file
    new_file = '{path}\\{name}.{ext}'.format(
        path=dest_path,
        name=name.split('.')[3],
        ext=ext
    )

    os.rename(file, new_file)
```

Comment: This works great for my purposes.  I just wanted to keep this in its current folder, so this works perfectly.  No worries about a singular magic number.  I was just looking for best practices advice.  This will be a clean approach for a large number of my use cases.  Apologies for the initial detail overload.